# python plotly choropleth dropdown + time slider

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, choropleth

I am trying to plot a choropleth map with a drop-down menu to select multiple variables and also show each variable with a time slider to display data over time.

```
import plotly
import numpy as np
  
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
  
# Reading sample data using pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.\
com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv')
  
data = [dict(type='choropleth',
             locations = df['code'].astype(str),
             z=df['total exports'].astype(float),
             locationmode='USA-states')]
  
# let's create some more additional, data
for i in range(5):
    data.append(data[0].copy())
    data[-1]['z'] = data[0]['z'] * np.random.rand(*data[0]['z'].shape)
  
# let's now create slider for map
steps = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    step = dict(method='restyle',
                args=['visible', [False] * len(data)],
                label='Year {}'.format(i + 1980))
    step['args'][1][i] = True
    steps.append(step)
  
slider = [dict(active=0,
                pad={"t": 1},
                steps=steps)]    
layout = dict(geo=dict(scope='usa',
                       projection={'type': 'albers usa'}),
              sliders=slider)
  
fig = dict(data=data, 
           layout=layout)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

This example is taken from: [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-a-choropleth-map-with-a-slider-using-plotly-in-python/)

Any ideas how to add another column as data points?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out the `animation_frame` argument in `plotly.express.choropleth` in Plotly Express.

https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.choropleth.html